# Docusign anchorString in textTabs

Tags: docusignapi

```
   I'm using envelopedefinition XML to add textTabs based on anchorString.
```

looks like anchorstring can ONLY be single string. if space in the string, it 
won't work. Does anyone have idea what I am doing wrong? 
if I use [Authorized] or [Representative], it works. 
if I use 2 strings combined with space like the following, it won't work.

```
 <textTabs>
    <text>
      <anchorString>Authorized Representative</anchorString>  -- this part does not work
      <anchorCaseSensitive>true</anchorCaseSensitive>
      <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
      <anchorMatchWholeWord>True</anchorMatchWholeWord>
      <name>Titel_Text</name>
      <anchorXOffset>1</anchorXOffset>
      <anchorYOffset>-18</anchorYOffset>
      <anchorUnits>Pixels</anchorUnits>
    </text>
</textTabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

A common problem in this circumstance is that the source string in the PDF is using a different character than a `space` character between the words. Try to copy/paste those characters to see.

Also:

1. Try turning off `MatchWholeWord.` Only use it if you get extraneous matches.
2. Try creating the template / tag using the web browser. See if it enables you to match the text / the location that you want. Depending on your use case, it is often easiest to create a template using the web user interface, and then select the template as part of your API call. (Vs creating the tags via the API call.)
3. If you can modify the document, add "sig1" to the source document, using white-colored letters so they won't be seen in the doc. Then anchor match on "sig1".

Comment: Larry, I turned MatchwholeWord out, not working.
I create template/tag in web browser in appdemo.docusign.com, and use same document, I can see textTag in web browser.
I modified document to add 'sig1' as anchorstring and set it to white color, works.  if I add 'sig 1' which has one space, it does not work. just wondered why it can not accept space in anchorstring.

Comment: My guess is that the space is not matching because it is not a regular space. What language is the document in? In any case, it sounds like you have a successful work-around by using sig1 or similar as your anchor text.

Comment: I define XML envelopedefinition in VB.  and I used crystal report 8.5 to export PDF File.  space works in other tags except Texttab.

Comment: So you're able to anchor some tags to "sig 1" but not others? Sounds like a bug. If you can share the document, please

Comment: ... please create a support case via https://goo.gl/TRRvbu I'm sorry for the problem and glad that there is a work-around.

Comment: <envelopeDefinition xmlns=http://www.docusign.com/restapi> 
   <emailSubject>  xxx  </emailSubject> 
   <emailBlurb>  xxx  </emailBlurb> 
   <AllowMarkup>true</AllowMarkup> 
   <status>sent</status> 
   <documents>  xxx  </documents> 
   <recipients> 
   <signers> 
   <signer> 
  <recipientId>1</recipientId> 
  <email>  xxx</email> 
  <name>  xxx</name> 
  <tabs> 
  <textTabs> 
<text> 
  <anchorString>Sig_Company</anchorString> 
  </text> 
  </textTabs> 
   </tabs> 
   </signer>
   </signers> 
   </recipients> 
   </envelopeDefinition>

Comment: the document is too long, can not paste all

Comment: Larry, I just created case in  goo.gl/TRRvbu

Answer (score 0):

In docusign developper documentation https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/get#signHere, there is a litlle paragraph on how they handle special characters in anchorstring (the documentation is in the matchWholeWord part.

> This functionality uses the following rules:
>
> Unless punctuation is specified in the anchorString, this functionality ignores punctuation and the following characters:
>
> $~><|^+=

I managed tu use an anchorstring which looks like "<user_1.signhere>" with the parameter matchWholeWord set to true.